# asp.net security won't validate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, security, asp.net-membership

I'm making an app that can validate (authenticate) a user in a wpf form.
I'm using asp .net security module. The database that was generated is present (I'm sure) and a user is added.

My code :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){   
        //MembershipCreateStatus result;
        //Membership.CreateUser("testuser", "Pass!", "test@test.com", "Hood", "Pine Hills", true, out result);
        String name=txtName.Text;
        String pas=txtPassword.Text;
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(name, pas))
            lblResult.Content = "correct!";
        else
            lblResult.Content = "wrong!";
    }
}
```

The problem is that it isn't correct.. even if I fill in the correct password and user.

Comment: but this is executed on your client side which does not have membership configured. It is you asp.net who has it, correct?

Comment: It's just a local project on my laptop.

Comment: in which .config file is membership configured?

Comment: the file is called app.config

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. Apparently I locked the user by trying the wrong password to much. in the conf file was stated that if a user tries a wrong password 3 times ' maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" ' The user will get locked.

By unlocking the user again. 
Membership.GetUser("testuser").UnlockUser();

Authentication was succesfull again.